# first letter uppercase in index

Tags: indexing, uppercase

I am currently using the following index:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside, openleft]{book}

\definecolor{DarkDarkPurple}{RGB}{63, 22, 59}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\newcommand{\boldindex}[1]{\textcolor{DarkPurple}{\textbf{#1}}\index{#1}}
\makeindex[intoc]

\begin{document}

\boldindex{Test}\\
\boldindex{tEst}\\
\boldindex{teSt}\\
\boldindex{tesT}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

How am I able to have index every word starting with an uppercase letter, while holding a lowercase in the text?

Comment: So you want that all those entries are treated as if they were “Test” and so indexed?

Comment: @egreg I would like it to have it in my index as: Test, TEst, TeSt, TesT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, make compilable examples: the definition for `DarkPurple` is missing and the `openleft` option does not exist for `book`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[intoc]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\boldindex}{m}
 {
  \textcolor{DarkPurple}{\textbf{#1}}
  \index{\char_titlecase:N #1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\colorlet{DarkPurple}{purple} % ???

\begin{document}

\boldindex{Test}
\boldindex{tEst}
\boldindex{teSt}
\boldindex{tesT}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course this will ***not*** work if the first letter is a composite character.